# Count how many items appear before an item with a specific ID

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have this project, and one of the tasks I need to do is find what page a specific object appears on. The object has a predefined ID, and the ID's appear in order from 0 to N, but they could potentially skip values.

Which means, obviously, that using the ID of the element I'm looking for won't work, as if it's 25, and there are supposed to be 10 items per page, but 8 of those items are missing, it would try to fit on page 3, but could only fit on page 2.

Here's what I have now, I was wondering if there was a better way:

```
int itemsPerPage = Convert.ToInt32(masterDbContext.Settings.First(x => x.Name == "ItemsPerPage").Value);
int itemCount = masterDbContext.Items.OrderBy(x => x.Id).TakeWhile(x => x.Id < currentItemId).Count();
int pageNumber = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)itemCount / itemsPerPage);

Response.Redirect("~/View/" + rootItem.Id + (pageNumber > 1 ? "/Page/" + pageNumber : ""));
```

If there's no better way to do this, that's fine. I just *hope* that there is, because I'm sure the `TakeWhile` can take, well, a while when I have thousands of `Items` in the database.

Do note: this method currently works it seems.

Comment: why do you need `GroupBy` here? wont `masterDbContext.Items.Count(x => x.Id < currentItemId);`work?

Comment: @ieaglle That worked perfectly!

Comment: and I'm almost certain that both versions produce exact the same SQL code. so that's just a code readability optimization, not performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it. Since you are ordering items by ID and counting how many of them with ID less than a number, you can just use that condition in `Count`:

```
 var itemsPerPage = Convert.ToInt32(masterDbContext.Settings.First(x => x.Name == "ItemsPerPage").Value); 
 var itemCount = masterDbContext.Items.Count(x => x.Id < currentItemId);
```

Also there is no direct SQL match for `TakeWhile` LINQ extension method. So you better of not using it, when you want to have your LINQ query translated to SQL

Comment: This worked perfectly! (Except for a condition I accidentally left out, but that's not your fault.) And I appreciate the explanation on the downfalls of `TakeWhile`. I never realized that it wouldn't work with the SQL. (Though it makes sense, I've never seen a SQL query that uses `TakeWhile` or anything that could look like it.) I guess the kicker that makes count work is that the id's are always in sequence, though while they may skip values they still go from low to high (always).

Comment: @EBrown glad it helped!

Comment: TakeWhile would have to be implemented with a cursor :-)

Comment: @EBrown `TakeWhile` should throw NotSupportedException but looks like you said it worked (in your question)? Strange enough.

Comment: @Hopeless Yeah, it seemed to work for me. (Unless that bit was being skipped in my initial scenario.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this uses some form of SQL provider, all you have to do is analogous to this in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT([Id])
FROM [Items]
WHERE [Id] < @currentItemId
```

C# LINQ:

```
masterDbContext.Items.Count(item => item.Id < currentItemId);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try something like

```
int itemCount = masterDbContext.Items.FindIndex(x => (x.Id == given_ID));
```

Comment: Please read the question: "but they could potentially skip values."

Comment: Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence within the entire List<T>. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx) so you'll get not 25 but 25-8 (in fact 16 az zero based)

Comment: Why do you assume that it is a `List<T>` ?

Comment: This is actually a `DbSet<T>`, which doesn't have a `FindIndex`.